# How to suppress "Undefined" errors before fetching data in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I have a simple page where I display some data that are fetched from the server.

Template:

```
<p>Order's customer name: {{ order.customer.name }}</p>
```

Javascript:

```
export default {
    data () { return { order: {} } },
    mounted () { this.fetchOrder() },
    methods: {
        fetchOrder () {
            /* get the order data asynchronously from the server */
            .success(function () { this.order = data_from_server })
        }
    }
}
```

Everything works just fine but in browser's console there is an error: "*Cannot read property 'name' of undefined*". Apparently the problem is that it takes some time to fetch the order data from the server and meanwhile it tries to access `order.customer.name`, which results in error, because `order.customer` is undefined.

How can I suppress this error? What's the best solution to this?

Of course, I can explicitly define the order structure (eg. `order: { customer: {} }`), but that doesn't seem nice to me, especially when the data structure grows to several-level-nested objects.

Comment: in typescript you would have `order.customer?.name` but in JS I'm afraind you'll have something "ugly" in the end anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    data: {name: 'daniel'},
    data2: {}
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  <p v-if="data" v-text="data.name"></p>
  <p v-if="data2" v-text="data2.name"></p>
</div>
```

You need to render it conditionally. Since data from the backend is not accessible from the very beginning, you should add a condition to display element only when the data is ready. See example.

```
<p>Order's customer name: <span v-if="order" v-text="order.customer.name"></span></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can test for `order.customer` :

```
{{ order.customer && order.customer.name }}
```

if `order.customer` is not defined, the expression evaluation will simply stop at the first term without throwing an error.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ternary operator to check

```
<p>Order's customer name: {{ order.customer?order.customer.name:'' }}</p>
```